# Multiple choice with figure options in exam class

Tags: multicol, exam

I am creating multiple choice questions using *exam class* however I faced two issues: 1). Want to have two columns choices but it displays by default as A, C, B, D, and 2). Figures in choices are bottom aligned instead of top alignment. Any suggestion? Below is my MWE:

> ```
> \documentclass{exam}
> \usepackage{multicol}
> \usepackage{graphicx}
> \begin{document}
>     \begin{questions}
>         \question
>         \begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\linewidth}
>         Consider the network graph shown in the figure, which of the following is NOT a \textit{tree} of this graph?
>             \begin{multicols}{2}
>                 \begin{choices}
>                     \choice
>                         \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}
>                     \choice
>                         \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-b}
>                     \choice
>                         \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-c}
>                     \CorrectChoice
>                         \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}
>                 \end{choices}
>             \end{multicols}
>     \end{minipage}
>     \hspace{2em}%
>     \begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\linewidth}
>         \vspace{-\baselineskip}
>         \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-a}
>     \end{minipage}
> \end{questions}
> \end{document}
> ```

Output after running the above code gives as:
[image]

However, I wish to have something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\linewidth}
        Consider the network graph shown in the figure, which of the following is NOT a \textit{tree} of this graph?
                \begin{choices}
            \begin{multicols}{2}
                    \choice
                        \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}}
                    \choice
                        \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-b}}
            \end{multicols}\par
            \begin{multicols}{2}
                    \choice
                        \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-c}}
                    \CorrectChoice
                        \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}}
            \end{multicols}
                \end{choices}
    \end{minipage}\hfill%
        \begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.30\linewidth},valign=t}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I used the [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package to get the desired top alignment. For the numbering schema I used two `multicols` environments instead of just one.

I also changed the `scale` option for `\includegraphics` to width`and changed some spaces to prevent overfull`\hbox`es.

Comment: this multicols environment gives "! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup" when used with \printanswers command. Any suggestion on what to avoid this situation please.

Comment: @Khaaba We need to see an example of the actual code that you are using. Since this is not directly related to the original question, the best thing to do is to open a fresh new question with this new issue. Please provide a MWE there allowing us to reproduce the error mentioned.

Comment: I have added actual code I am using with your last suggestion. Usually when I used \printanswers command, the \CorrectChoice should make the partchoice boldface indicating that it is the correct answer out of choices given therein.

Comment: @Khaaba No. I didn'¿t mean add the code in the original question. I meant open a fresh new question. I think it's better.

Comment: @Khaaba The other answer doesn't have problems with `\printanswers`.

Comment: I still can't get the error resolved! I moved the issue in new question. Sorry, I should have provided the complete features in the same code from the beginning. I expected that it would work like text choices but it didn't when we have figure choices.

Answer (score 3):

egreg has answers for almost every thing. For your first issue, you may use this solution give by egereg:

```
%%------------------egreg's code starts-------------
\usepackage{environ,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_undefine:N \choices
\cs_undefine:N \endchoices
\NewEnviron{choices}{%
  \par\nopagebreak
  \harish_dochoices:V \BODY
  \par
}
\tl_new:N \l_harish_choices_tl
\seq_new:N \l_harish_choices_seq
\seq_new:N \l_harish_choices_final_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \harish_dochoices:n #1
 {
  \setcounter{choice}{0}
  \tl_set:Nn \l_harish_choices_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_harish_choices_tl { \CorrectChoice } { \choice* }
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_harish_choices_seq { \choice } \l_harish_choices_tl
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_harish_choices_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_harish_choices_final_seq \l_harish_choices_seq
   { \exp_not:n { \makechoice ##1 } }
  %\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_harish_choices_final_seq { \makebox[.5\linewidth][l]{##1}\hspace{0pt plus .3\linewidth} }
% }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_harish_choices_final_seq
   {
    \makebox[.5\linewidth][l]{
      \parbox[t]{.45\linewidth}{\raggedright \hangindent1.5em ##1\strut}
    }\hspace{0pt plus .3\linewidth}
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \harish_dochoices:n { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter
    \NewDocumentCommand{\makechoice}{s}
 {%
  \stepcounter{choice}
  \makebox[1.2em][l]{\IfBooleanT{#1}{\ifprintanswers\CorrectChoice@Emphasis\fi}\Alph{choice}.}
 }
\makeatother
\CorrectChoiceEmphasis{\bfseries\boldmath}

%%------------------egreg's code ends-------------
```

He helped me once upon a time when I was a victim of similar requirement while I was doing some question paper.

For the second issue, you can load the `adjustbox` package (as Gonzalo did) but with `export` option. This will make keys like `valign` etc available for `\includegraphics` command. So you have to use

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=t]{example-image-a}
```

Remember that in this case `graphicx` is loaded by `adjustbox`.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

%%------------------egreg's code starts-------------
\usepackage{environ,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_undefine:N \choices
\cs_undefine:N \endchoices
\NewEnviron{choices}{%
  \par\nopagebreak
  \harish_dochoices:V \BODY
  \par
}
\tl_new:N \l_harish_choices_tl
\seq_new:N \l_harish_choices_seq
\seq_new:N \l_harish_choices_final_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \harish_dochoices:n #1
 {
  \setcounter{choice}{0}
  \tl_set:Nn \l_harish_choices_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_harish_choices_tl { \CorrectChoice } { \choice* }
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_harish_choices_seq { \choice } \l_harish_choices_tl
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_harish_choices_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_harish_choices_final_seq \l_harish_choices_seq
   { \exp_not:n { \makechoice ##1 } }
  %\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_harish_choices_final_seq { \makebox[.5\linewidth][l]{##1}\hspace{0pt plus .3\linewidth} }
% }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_harish_choices_final_seq
   {
    \makebox[.5\linewidth][l]{
      \parbox[t]{.45\linewidth}{\raggedright \hangindent1.5em ##1\strut}
    }\hspace{0pt plus .3\linewidth}
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \harish_dochoices:n { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter
    \NewDocumentCommand{\makechoice}{s}
 {%
  \stepcounter{choice}
  \makebox[1.2em][l]{\IfBooleanT{#1}{\ifprintanswers\CorrectChoice@Emphasis\fi}\Alph{choice}.}
 }
\makeatother
\CorrectChoiceEmphasis{\bfseries\boldmath}

%%------------------egreg's code ends-------------

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\linewidth}
        Consider the network graph shown in the figure, which of the following is NOT a \textit{tree} of this graph?
            %\begin{multicols}{2}
                \begin{choices}
                    \choice
                        \includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=t]{example-image-a}
                    \choice
                        \includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=t]{example-image-b}
                    \choice
                        \includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=t]{example-image-c}
                    \CorrectChoice
                        \includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=t]{example-image-a}
                \end{choices}
            %\end{multicols}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
        \vspace{-\baselineskip}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are not struck with `exam` class, I suggest you to use `exsheets` class which has a native support for this kind of lists.

Comment: The above code gives the following error when run using with TexWorks[pdflatex] on MacTeX 2015: ! Undefined control sequence.
\harish_dochoices:n ...hoice *}\seq_set_split:NnV 
                                                  \l_harish_choices_seq {\ch...
l.64                 \end{choices}
                                  
?  Have I missed anything?

Comment: @Khaaba I don't have mactex. Sorry. The code works with latest miktex for me.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It works on MikTeX. Just tested it on my chamber pc. Figure choices are too close to each other vertically though. Here is another good option given last evening by touhami at [![http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272278/multiple-choice-question-with-figure-choices-gives-error-when-used-with-printan/272297#272297]]