# Multiple choice question with figure choices gives error when used with \printanswers command in exam class

Tags: multicol, exam

This question has been modified from [this question with added feature](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272224/multiple-choice-with-figure-options-in-exam-class). However, when I used `\printanswers` command, the code gives an error the following error:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endmulticols ->\par \if@boxedmulticols \egroup 
                                                \balance@columns \return@non...
l.24             \end{multicols}

?
```

My MWE code modified with suggestion from *Gonzalo Medina* when used with `\noprintanswers` is given below:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\printanswers
\noprintanswers
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\linewidth}
    Consider the network graph shown in the figure, which of the following is NOT a \textit{tree} of this graph?
            \begin{choices}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
                \choice
                    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}}
                \choice
                    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-b}}
        \end{multicols}\par
        \begin{multicols}{2}
                \choice
                    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-c}}
                \CorrectChoice
                    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}}
        \end{multicols}
            \end{choices}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.30\linewidth},valign=t}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
\end{adjustbox}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

When `\printanswers` command is used, it should give the output like this highlighting the `partlabel` corresponding to the `\CorrectChoice`:
[image]

Any suggestion to solve the error when used `\printanswer` command in the given code!

Comment: Ther other answer to your previous question works in this case too. Is there any reason you don't want to use it?

Comment: Have you tried @HarishKumar's answer? In your comment on the other answer to your other question, you don't make this clear. Presumably you'd at least get a different error in that case?

Comment: I will see to it Harish. I wanted minimum changes to the original code and found convenient to use with what Gonzalo has suggested. It proved good and working as long as I use \noprintanswers command to the code. But it results an error when I put \printanswers command.

Comment: This happen only if `\CorrectChoice` is last. In this case you can try with`\CorrectChoice\endgroup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** In this solution, we define new environment `multichoices` that works like multicols, by defaut it hase two columns but one can set more if needed.

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{multichoices}[1][2]{%
\begin{multicols}{#1}}{%
\if@correctchoice \endgroup \fi
\end{multicols}}
\makeatother
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\printanswers
%\noprintanswers

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{multichoices}[1][2]{%
\begin{multicols}{#1}}{%
\if@correctchoice \endgroup \fi
\end{multicols}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\linewidth}
    Consider the network graph shown in the figure, which of the following is NOT a \textit{tree} of this graph?
            \begin{choices}
        \begin{multichoices}
                \choice
                    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}}
                \choice
                    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-b}}
        \end{multichoices}\par
        \begin{multichoices}
                \CorrectChoice
                    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}}
                \choice
                    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-c}}
        \end{multichoices}
            \end{choices}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.30\linewidth},valign=t}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
\end{adjustbox}


    \question 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\linewidth}
    Consider the network graph shown in the figure, which of the following is NOT a \textit{tree} of this graph?
            \begin{choices}
        \begin{multichoices}
                \choice
                    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}}
                \choice
                    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-b}}
        \end{multichoices}\par
        \begin{multichoices}
                \choice
                    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-c}}
                \CorrectChoice
                    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}}
        \end{multichoices}
            \end{choices}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.30\linewidth},valign=t}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
\end{adjustbox}

    \question 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\linewidth}
    Consider the network graph shown in the figure, which of the following is NOT a \textit{tree} of this graph?
            \begin{choices}
        \begin{multichoices}
                \choice
                       bla bla
                \choice
                       bla bla
        \end{multichoices}\par
        \begin{multichoices}
                \choice
                       bla bla
                \CorrectChoice
                    bla bla
        \end{multichoices}
            \end{choices}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.30\linewidth},valign=t}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
\end{adjustbox}


    \question 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\linewidth}
    Consider the network graph shown in the figure, which of the following is NOT a \textit{tree} of this graph?
            \begin{choices}
        \begin{multichoices}
                \choice
                       bla bla
                \choice
                       bla bla
        \end{multichoices}\par
        \begin{multichoices}
                \CorrectChoice
                       bla bla
                \choice
                    bla bla
        \end{multichoices}
            \end{choices}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.30\linewidth},valign=t}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
\end{adjustbox}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Touhami, can you please add another question in which choices are texts only along with this figure choices? Code runs but correctchoice label is missing when I use \printanswers command? May be I need little more understanding of the tricks you have provided.

Comment: you're right I can't see it now, I will try later.

Comment: it worked without the aforementioned error in the original question with tikzpicture environment instead of includegraphics. Now after the recent update, I have started getting the aforementioned error with tikzpicture: `! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup`. I can't get a clue to fix it. Could you please help me?

Comment: @Khaaba please ask a new question.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I have put the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/452545/18678)