# Make options al horizontal instead vertical in multiple choice

Tags: templates, exam, questionnaire, examdesign

I want to type some multiple choice questions. I have the following code. The problem is that in some questions I need options in one line and evenly spaced, and in some questions I need two in one line and evenly spaced. How can I do that. 
I know that there are some answers related to this but I tried to figure out from that how to change this code, but every time I get an error and I don't want to use a different code all together. It will be nice if I am able to do this in this very code.

Thanks for the help in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcounter{choice}
\renewcommand\thechoice{($\alph{choice}$)}
\newcommand\choicelabel{\thechoice}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{choices}%
  {\list{\choicelabel}%
     {\usecounter{choice}\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}%
       \settowidth{\leftmargin}{W.\hskip\labelsep\hskip 0 em}%
       \def\choice{%
         \item
       } % choice
       \labelwidth\leftmargin\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
       \topsep=0pt
       \partopsep=0pt
     }%
  }%
  {\endlist}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\def\CChoice{%
      \choice
      \addanswer{\theenumi}{\thechoice}%
    }
    \let\CChoice\CChoice
%    \par % Uncomment this to have choices always start a new line
   % \let\par\@empty
    % If we're continuing the paragraph containing the question,
    % then leave a bit of space before the first choice:
    \ifvmode\else\enskip\fi
    \ignorespaces
  %
  {}
\makeatother
\newbox\allanswers
\setbox\allanswers=\hbox{}
\newcommand{\addanswer}[2]{%
  \global\setbox\allanswers=\hbox{\unhbox\allanswers \quad #1.~#2}%
}
\newcommand{\showanswers}{%
  \vfill
  \begin{center}
    Answers
  \end{center}
  \unhbox\allanswers
}





%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item One of these things is not like the others; one of these things
  is not the same.  Which one doesn't belong?
  \begin{choices}
    \choice George
    \choice Paul
    \choice John
    \CChoice Ringo
  \end{choices}
\item What was the color of George Washinton's white horse?
  \begin{choices}
    \choice Green
    \CChoice Yellow
    \choice White
    \choice Socrates    
  \end{choices}
\item What was the color of George Washinton's white horse?
  \begin{choices}
    \choice Green
    \choice Yellow
    \CChoice White
    \choice Socrates
  \end{choices}
\item One of these things is not like the others; one of these things
  is not the same.  Which one doesn't belong?

  \begin{choices}
    \choice George
    \choice Paul
    \choice John
    \choice Ringo
  \end{choices}
\item What was the color of George Washinton's white horse?

  \begin{choices}
    \choice Green
    \choice Yellow
    \choice White
    \choice Socrates    
  \end{choices}
\end{enumerate}

\showanswers
\end{document}
```

[image: The out put is the following]

Comment: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Teacher%27s_Corner

Comment: Thanks. But I am not using Exam class.

Comment: Look at [tasks](https://ctan.org/pkg/tasks) package.

Comment: Sorry, i cannot use my phone as well at night as i do at day time. What i meant to link was [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Teacher%27s_Corner#Exsheets) which especially mentions `tasks` (as Carla did above). There even is an image of the [example-output](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:TeacherscornerExsheets.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272278/multiple-choice-question-with-figure-choices-gives-error-when-used-with-printan/272297#272297) question: we create a multicolumn environment:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{multichoices}[1][2]{%
\begin{multicols}{#1}}{%
\end{multicols}}
\makeatother
```

and use it in the `choices` environment. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcounter{choice}
\renewcommand\thechoice{($\alph{choice}$)}
\newcommand\choicelabel{\thechoice}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{choices}%
  {\list{\choicelabel}%
     {\usecounter{choice}\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}%
       \settowidth{\leftmargin}{W.\hskip\labelsep\hskip 0 em}%
       \def\choice{%
         \item
       } % choice
       \labelwidth\leftmargin\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
       \topsep=0pt
       \partopsep=0pt
     }%
  }%
  {\endlist}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\def\CChoice{%
      \choice
      \addanswer{\theenumi}{\thechoice}%
    }
    \let\CChoice\CChoice
%    \par % Uncomment this to have choices always start a new line
   % \let\par\@empty
    % If we're continuing the paragraph containing the question,
    % then leave a bit of space before the first choice:
    \ifvmode\else\enskip\fi
    \ignorespaces
  %
  {}
\makeatother
\newbox\allanswers
\setbox\allanswers=\hbox{}
\newcommand{\addanswer}[2]{%
  \global\setbox\allanswers=\hbox{\unhbox\allanswers \quad #1.~#2}%
}
\newcommand{\showanswers}{%
  \vfill
  \begin{center}
    Answers
  \end{center}
  \unhbox\allanswers
}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{multichoices}[1][2]{%
\begin{multicols}{#1}}{%
\end{multicols}}
\makeatother

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item One of these things is not like the others; one of these things
  is not the same.  Which one doesn't belong?
  \begin{choices}
   \begin{multichoices}[4]
    \choice George
    \choice Paul
    \choice John
    \CChoice Ringo
   \end{multichoices}
  \end{choices}
\item What was the color of George Washinton's white horse?
  \begin{choices}
   \begin{multichoices}[2]
    \choice Green
    \CChoice Yellow
    \choice White
    \choice Socrates    
   \end{multichoices}
  \end{choices}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

BTW: why not use the `exam` class?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Its part of a bigger project and the document class is book so I can add another class.