# Recent update of exam class gives an error on earlier working file

Tags: tikz-pgf, multicol, circuitikz, exam

This question has been derieved from two questions- [the first question here solved by @Gonzalo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/272224/18678) and [the follow up question here solved by @touhami](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/272278/18678). Now, I get the same error that of the follow up question when I use `\printanswers` command **with tikzpicture environment**:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endmulticols ->\par \if@boxedmulticols \egroup 
                                                \balance@columns \return@non...
l.24             \end{multicols}

?
```

my MWE *which was working earlier* with `\printanswers` command is given below:

```
% !TeX TS-program=pdfLaTeX
\documentclass{exam}
\printanswers
\noprintanswers

\pointsinrightmargin
\bracketedpoints

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, circuits.ee.IEC,positioning, decorations.markings}
\usepackage[american voltages, american currents, siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[labelfont=,textfont={it}]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Fig.,font=footnotesize} 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{multichoices}[1][2]{%
\begin{multicols}{#1}}{%
    \if@correctchoice \endgroup \fi
\end{multicols}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\linewidth}
Consider the graph shown in the Fig.~\ref{fig:Q1}, which of the following is NOT \textit{a tree} of this graph?
\begin{choices}
    \begin{multichoices}
        \choice
            \adjustbox{valign=t}{%
                \scalebox{0.5}{%
                \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=center, x=4cm, y=4cm] 
                    \coordinate [label=below left:\textcolor{blue}{}] (A) at (0.0,0.0);
                    \coordinate [label=above left:\textcolor{blue}{}] (B) at (0.0,0.8);
                    \coordinate [label=above right:\textcolor{blue}{}] (C) at (0.8,0.8);
                    \coordinate [label=below right:\textcolor{blue}{}] (D) at (0.8,0.0);
                    \draw (C) to (B);
                    \draw (D) to [bend right=55] (1.1,0.9) to (1.1,0.9) 
                        to [bend right=55] (B);
                    \draw (B) to [bend right=40] (-0.4,0.45) to (-0.4,0.35) 
                        to [bend right=40] (A);
                    \fill (B) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (D) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (A) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (C) circle(2pt);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                } %EOS
            }% adjustbox
        \choice
            \adjustbox{valign=t}{%
                \scalebox{0.5}{%
                \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=center, x=4cm, y=4cm] 
                    \coordinate [label=below left:\textcolor{blue}{}] (A) at (0.0,0.0); 
                    \coordinate [label=above left:\textcolor{blue}{}] (B) at (0.0,0.8); 
                    \coordinate [label=above right:\textcolor{blue}{}] (C) at (0.8,0.8); 
                    \coordinate [label=below right:\textcolor{blue}{}] (D) at (0.8,0.0); 
                    \draw (A) to (C);
                    \draw (D) to [bend right=55] (1.1,0.9) to (1.1,0.9) 
                        to [bend right=55] (B);
                    \draw (B) to [bend right=40] (-0.4,0.45) to (-0.4,0.35) 
                        to [bend right=40] (A);
                    \fill (B) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (D) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (A) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (C) circle(2pt);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                } %EOS
            }% adjustbox
    \end{multichoices}\par
    \begin{multichoices}
        \CorrectChoice
            \adjustbox{valign=t}{%
                \scalebox{0.5}{%
                \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=center, x=4cm, y=4cm] 
                    \coordinate [label=below left:\textcolor{blue}{}] (A) at (0.0,0.0); 
                    \coordinate [label=above left:\textcolor{blue}{}] (B) at (0.0,0.8); 
                    \coordinate [label=above right:\textcolor{blue}{}] (C) at (0.8,0.8);
                    \coordinate [label=below right:\textcolor{blue}{}] (D) at (0.8,0.0); 
                    \draw (A) to (B);
                    \draw (C) to (B);
                    \draw (D) to [bend right=55] (1.1,0.9) to (1.1,0.9) 
                        to [bend right=55] (B);
                    \draw (B) to [bend right=40] (-0.4,0.45) to (-0.4,0.35) 
                        to [bend right=40] (A);
                    \fill (B) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (D) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (A) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (C) circle(2pt);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                } %EOS
            }% adjustbox
        \choice
            \adjustbox{valign=t}{%
                \scalebox{0.5}{%
                \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=center, x=4cm, y=4cm] 
                    \coordinate [label=below left:\textcolor{blue}{}] (A) at (0.0,0.0);
                    \coordinate [label=above left:\textcolor{blue}{}] (B) at (0.0,0.8);
                    \coordinate [label=above right:\textcolor{blue}{}] (C) at (0.8,0.8); 
                    \coordinate [label=below right:\textcolor{blue}{}] (D) at (0.8,0.0);
                    \draw (D) to (C);
                    \draw (D) to [bend right=55] (1.1,0.9) to (1.1,0.9) 
                        to [bend right=55] (B);
                    \draw (B) to [bend right=40] (-0.4,0.45) to (-0.4,0.35) 
                        to [bend right=40] (A);
                    \fill (B) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (D) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (A) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (C) circle(2pt);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                } %EOS
            }% adjustbox
    \end{multichoices}
\end{choices}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.30\linewidth},valign=t}
    \centering%
    \scalebox{0.68}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=center, x=4cm, y=4cm] 
        \coordinate [label=below left:\textcolor{blue}{}] (A) at (0.0,0.0);
        \coordinate [label=above left:\textcolor{blue}{}] (B) at (0.0,0.8);
        \coordinate [label=above right:\textcolor{blue}{}] (C) at (0.8,0.8);
        \coordinate [label=below right:\textcolor{blue}{}] (D) at (0.8,0.0);
        \draw (A) to (B);
        \draw (C) to (B);
        \draw (D) to (C);
        \draw (A) to (D);
        \draw (A) to (C);
        \draw (D) to [bend right=55] (1.1,0.9) to (1.1,0.9) to [bend right=55] (B);
        \draw (B) to [bend right=40] (-0.4,0.45) to (-0.4,0.35) to [bend right=40] (A);
        \fill (B) circle(2pt);
        \fill (D) circle(2pt);
        \fill (A) circle(2pt);
        \fill (C) circle(2pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}} %EoS
    \captionof{figure}{\label{fig:Q1}}
\end{adjustbox}


\question 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\linewidth}
    Consider the network graph shown in the figure, which of the following is NOT a \textit{tree} of this graph?
    \begin{choices}
        \begin{multichoices}
            \choice
                \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}}
            \choice
                \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-b}}
        \end{multichoices}\par
        \begin{multichoices}
            \choice
                \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-c}}
            \CorrectChoice
                \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}}
        \end{multichoices}
    \end{choices}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.30\linewidth},valign=t}
    \centering%
    \scalebox{0.68}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=3.22cm,y=3.22cm]
    \coordinate [label=above left:\textcolor{blue}{}] (O) at (1.0,1.0);
    \coordinate [label=above right:\textcolor{blue}{}] (A) at (0.0,1.0);
    \coordinate [label=below:\textcolor{blue}{}] (B) at (1.0,2.0);
    \coordinate [label=below:\textcolor{blue}{}] (C) at (2.0,1.0);  
    \coordinate [label=above:\textcolor{blue}{}] (D) at (1.0,0.0);  
    \draw ($(D)+(0.0,0.0)$) node[circ]{}  to [R, l=5<\ohm>] ($(O)+(0.0,0.0)$) node[circ]{} 
        to ($(O)+(0.2,0.0)$) to [V, l_=2<\volt>] (A) node[circ]{} 
        to [R, l=3<\ohm>, label/align=straight] (B) 
        to [R, l=4<\ohm>, label/align=straight] ($(C)+(0.0,0.0)$) node[circ]{}  
        to [R, l=2<\ohm>, label/align=straight] ($(D)+(0.0,0.0)$) 
        to [I, l=2<\ampere>, label/align=straight]($(A)+(0.0,0.0)$) node[circ]{} ;
    \draw ($(B)+(0.0,0.0)$) node[circ]{} to ($(B)+(0.0,-0.2)$) to [cI, l=$i_x$] ($(O)+(0.0,0.0)$) 
        to [I, l=1<\ampere>] ($(C)+(-0.2,0.0)$) to ($(C)+(0.0,0.0)$);
    \draw[-stealth] ($(O)+(-0.06,-0.06)$) to node[left]{$i_x$} ($(O)+(-0.06,-0.3)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}} %EoS
\end{adjustbox}


\question 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\linewidth}
    Consider the network graph shown in the figure, which of the following is NOT a \textit{tree} of this graph?
    \begin{choices}
        \begin{multichoices}
            \choice
                bla bla
            \choice
                bla bla
        \end{multichoices}\par
        \begin{multichoices}
            \choice
                bla bla
            \CorrectChoice
                bla bla
        \end{multichoices}
    \end{choices}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.30\linewidth},valign=t}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image} 
\end{adjustbox}


\question 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\linewidth}
    Consider the network graph shown in the figure, which of the following is NOT a \textit{tree} of this graph?
    \begin{choices}
        \begin{multichoices}
            \choice
                bla bla
            \choice
                bla bla
        \end{multichoices}\par
        \begin{multichoices}
            \CorrectChoice
                bla bla
            \choice
                bla bla
        \end{multichoices}
    \end{choices}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.30\linewidth},valign=t}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image} 
\end{adjustbox} 
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

The output after running the above code with `\noprintanswers` command is
[image: here]

Comment: The code you post does *not* produce an error on my TeXLive 2018 distribution. What has one to do to get the error message?

Comment: @marmot there is an error when `\noprintanswers` is commented

Comment: @JLeonV.  there is an error when `\noprintanswers` is commented

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With he new version, one need to (re)define the environment `multichoices` like this

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{multichoices}[1][2]{%
\begin{multicols}{#1}}{%
\if@correctchoice  \color@endgroup \endgroup \fi
\end{multicols}}
\makeatother
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{exam}
\printanswers
%\noprintanswers

\pointsinrightmargin
\bracketedpoints

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, circuits.ee.IEC,positioning, decorations.markings}
\usepackage[american voltages, american currents, siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[labelfont=,textfont={it}]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Fig.,font=footnotesize} 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{multichoices}[1][2]{%
\begin{multicols}{#1}}{%
    \if@correctchoice \color@endgroup \endgroup \fi
\end{multicols}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\linewidth}
Consider the graph shown in the Fig.~\ref{fig:Q1}, which of the following is NOT \textit{a tree} of this graph?
\begin{choices}
    \begin{multichoices}
        \choice
            \adjustbox{valign=t}{%
                \scalebox{0.5}{%
                \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=center, x=4cm, y=4cm] 
                    \coordinate [label=below left:\textcolor{blue}{}] (A) at (0.0,0.0);
                    \coordinate [label=above left:\textcolor{blue}{}] (B) at (0.0,0.8);
                    \coordinate [label=above right:\textcolor{blue}{}] (C) at (0.8,0.8);
                    \coordinate [label=below right:\textcolor{blue}{}] (D) at (0.8,0.0);
                    \draw (C) to (B);
                    \draw (D) to [bend right=55] (1.1,0.9) to (1.1,0.9) 
                        to [bend right=55] (B);
                    \draw (B) to [bend right=40] (-0.4,0.45) to (-0.4,0.35) 
                        to [bend right=40] (A);
                    \fill (B) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (D) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (A) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (C) circle(2pt);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                } %EOS
            }% adjustbox
        \choice
            \adjustbox{valign=t}{%
                \scalebox{0.5}{%
                \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=center, x=4cm, y=4cm] 
                    \coordinate [label=below left:\textcolor{blue}{}] (A) at (0.0,0.0); 
                    \coordinate [label=above left:\textcolor{blue}{}] (B) at (0.0,0.8); 
                    \coordinate [label=above right:\textcolor{blue}{}] (C) at (0.8,0.8); 
                    \coordinate [label=below right:\textcolor{blue}{}] (D) at (0.8,0.0); 
                    \draw (A) to (C);
                    \draw (D) to [bend right=55] (1.1,0.9) to (1.1,0.9) 
                        to [bend right=55] (B);
                    \draw (B) to [bend right=40] (-0.4,0.45) to (-0.4,0.35) 
                        to [bend right=40] (A);
                    \fill (B) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (D) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (A) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (C) circle(2pt);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                } %EOS
            }% adjustbox
    \end{multichoices}\par
    \begin{multichoices}
        \CorrectChoice
            \adjustbox{valign=t}{%
                \scalebox{0.5}{%
                \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=center, x=4cm, y=4cm] 
                    \coordinate [label=below left:\textcolor{blue}{}] (A) at (0.0,0.0); 
                    \coordinate [label=above left:\textcolor{blue}{}] (B) at (0.0,0.8); 
                    \coordinate [label=above right:\textcolor{blue}{}] (C) at (0.8,0.8);
                    \coordinate [label=below right:\textcolor{blue}{}] (D) at (0.8,0.0); 
                    \draw (A) to (B);
                    \draw (C) to (B);
                    \draw (D) to [bend right=55] (1.1,0.9) to (1.1,0.9) 
                        to [bend right=55] (B);
                    \draw (B) to [bend right=40] (-0.4,0.45) to (-0.4,0.35) 
                        to [bend right=40] (A);
                    \fill (B) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (D) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (A) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (C) circle(2pt);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                } %EOS
            }% adjustbox
        \choice
            \adjustbox{valign=t}{%
                \scalebox{0.5}{%
                \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=center, x=4cm, y=4cm] 
                    \coordinate [label=below left:\textcolor{blue}{}] (A) at (0.0,0.0);
                    \coordinate [label=above left:\textcolor{blue}{}] (B) at (0.0,0.8);
                    \coordinate [label=above right:\textcolor{blue}{}] (C) at (0.8,0.8); 
                    \coordinate [label=below right:\textcolor{blue}{}] (D) at (0.8,0.0);
                    \draw (D) to (C);
                    \draw (D) to [bend right=55] (1.1,0.9) to (1.1,0.9) 
                        to [bend right=55] (B);
                    \draw (B) to [bend right=40] (-0.4,0.45) to (-0.4,0.35) 
                        to [bend right=40] (A);
                    \fill (B) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (D) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (A) circle(2pt);
                    \fill (C) circle(2pt);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                } %EOS
            }% adjustbox
    \end{multichoices}
\end{choices}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.30\linewidth},valign=t}
    \centering%
    \scalebox{0.68}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=center, x=4cm, y=4cm] 
        \coordinate [label=below left:\textcolor{blue}{}] (A) at (0.0,0.0);
        \coordinate [label=above left:\textcolor{blue}{}] (B) at (0.0,0.8);
        \coordinate [label=above right:\textcolor{blue}{}] (C) at (0.8,0.8);
        \coordinate [label=below right:\textcolor{blue}{}] (D) at (0.8,0.0);
        \draw (A) to (B);
        \draw (C) to (B);
        \draw (D) to (C);
        \draw (A) to (D);
        \draw (A) to (C);
        \draw (D) to [bend right=55] (1.1,0.9) to (1.1,0.9) to [bend right=55] (B);
        \draw (B) to [bend right=40] (-0.4,0.45) to (-0.4,0.35) to [bend right=40] (A);
        \fill (B) circle(2pt);
        \fill (D) circle(2pt);
        \fill (A) circle(2pt);
        \fill (C) circle(2pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}} %EoS
    \captionof{figure}{\label{fig:Q1}}
\end{adjustbox}


\question 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\linewidth}
    Consider the network graph shown in the figure, which of the following is NOT a \textit{tree} of this graph?
    \begin{choices}
        \begin{multichoices}
            \choice
                \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}}
            \choice
                \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-b}}
        \end{multichoices}\par
        \begin{multichoices}
            \choice
                \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-c}}
            \CorrectChoice
                \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}}
        \end{multichoices}
    \end{choices}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.30\linewidth},valign=t}
    \centering%
    \scalebox{0.68}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=3.22cm,y=3.22cm]
    \coordinate [label=above left:\textcolor{blue}{}] (O) at (1.0,1.0);
    \coordinate [label=above right:\textcolor{blue}{}] (A) at (0.0,1.0);
    \coordinate [label=below:\textcolor{blue}{}] (B) at (1.0,2.0);
    \coordinate [label=below:\textcolor{blue}{}] (C) at (2.0,1.0);  
    \coordinate [label=above:\textcolor{blue}{}] (D) at (1.0,0.0);  
    \draw ($(D)+(0.0,0.0)$) node[circ]{}  to [R, l=5<\ohm>] ($(O)+(0.0,0.0)$) node[circ]{} 
        to ($(O)+(0.2,0.0)$) to [V, l_=2<\volt>] (A) node[circ]{} 
        to [R, l=3<\ohm>, label/align=straight] (B) 
        to [R, l=4<\ohm>, label/align=straight] ($(C)+(0.0,0.0)$) node[circ]{}  
        to [R, l=2<\ohm>, label/align=straight] ($(D)+(0.0,0.0)$) 
        to [I, l=2<\ampere>, label/align=straight]($(A)+(0.0,0.0)$) node[circ]{} ;
    \draw ($(B)+(0.0,0.0)$) node[circ]{} to ($(B)+(0.0,-0.2)$) to [cI, l=$i_x$] ($(O)+(0.0,0.0)$) 
        to [I, l=1<\ampere>] ($(C)+(-0.2,0.0)$) to ($(C)+(0.0,0.0)$);
    \draw[-stealth] ($(O)+(-0.06,-0.06)$) to node[left]{$i_x$} ($(O)+(-0.06,-0.3)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}} %EoS
\end{adjustbox}


\question 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\linewidth}
    Consider the network graph shown in the figure, which of the following is NOT a \textit{tree} of this graph?
    \begin{choices}
        \begin{multichoices}
            \choice
                bla bla
            \choice
                bla bla
        \end{multichoices}\par
        \begin{multichoices}
            \choice
                bla bla
            \CorrectChoice
                bla bla
        \end{multichoices}
    \end{choices}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.30\linewidth},valign=t}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image} 
\end{adjustbox}


\question 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\linewidth}
    Consider the network graph shown in the figure, which of the following is NOT a \textit{tree} of this graph?
    \begin{choices}
        \begin{multichoices}
            \choice
                bla bla
            \choice
                bla bla
        \end{multichoices}\par
        \begin{multichoices}
            \CorrectChoice
                bla bla
            \choice
                bla bla
        \end{multichoices}
    \end{choices}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.30\linewidth},valign=t}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image} 
\end{adjustbox} 
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```